# Crop or mask out pixels outside the region of interest

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

I want eliminate pixels outside of my ROI before doing further processing on my images, and I was wondering if there is a nice way to get borders of the ROI. To better illustrate my goal, I am attaching two examples images here:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHoXF.png),[ROI of image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JezIf.png), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDM5y.png), [ROI of image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwKk0.png)

Sorry I am not able to post images directly yet, please click on the links to see them.
The red lines are basically borders of ROIs drawn by hand.

Thanks in advance.
Xinlong

Edit:I am attaching a few raw data for better understanding of my questions:

[raw data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1jj9.jpg),[raw data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aEDN.jpg),[raw data3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiNN5.jpg)

Comment: Do you already have the ROI clearly defined? You said the red lines were hand drawn, so in your program, how is your ROI defined? If you already have a clearly defined ROI in your code, then just get its bounding box, then crop the rest, would that be what you want?

Comment: There are actually 3 parts on the image, and I need to keep the middle part which was marked by the red lines. However, due to the difference among image files (I have hundreds of them), I am trying to get a method to mark the middle area automatically based on the distribution of those stripes.

Comment: I checked all your questions about X-ray images of batteries, looks like an interesting problem, I would like to know more. First of all, if there is way to re-scan those batteries under X-ray with better parameters, then the image should be easier to process; secondly, what is the original images' pixel depth and format? You posted jpg files, I hope you can have better quality raw files; thirdly, what is your final goal? In one of your other questions you were asking counting the layers, is this the final goal?

Comment: Thank you for spending time on my questions. Yes, the final goal is to count the number battery anode layers, which are usually at the middle part of my posted images. My current idea is to keep the only part of anode, and then count the number of layers. Actually, there is another challenge that the last a few layers are usually not clear enough because of the limited penetration ability of the X-ray machine, and unfortunately it is not easy to better images. For better understanding of this issue, I am attaching 3 typical raw data files. If you need the cropped ones, please let me know.

Comment: Are your raw image just those jpg images? Do you have any lossless, higher pixel-depth images? Are you able to modify the X-ray machine configuration to get better images?

Comment: Do you have a photo of the actual battery you are working on? Hard to imaging what the real thing looks like and what's the inner structure.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have actual battery photos, and these are the best quality photos we get from the x-ray camera.

Comment: Well.. than that's going to be difficult, even if possible..